# Collection of Undergraduate, Graduate, and PhD theses?

Tags: thesis, online-publication

Is there some webpage with a collection of thousands of theses of undergraduates, graduates, and PhD students from all kinds of sciences and where they are freely accessible like on ArXiv or (mostly) adsabs.harvard.edu?

Answer (score 1):

http://pqdtopen.proquest.com/search.html,

https://oatd.org/,

or library services of individual universities.

Answer (score 0):

researchgate.net has research from many academics who choose to self-upload, might be a good place to start off.

Comment: Don't you have to have an account there?

Comment: @Lucas , Yes I think so. Also one other possible route is to search your topic using google scholar, then view the papers which have cited the seminal research in your topic area.